# Mongodb geoWithin google maps bounds

Tags: google-maps, mongodb

I'm kind of new to mongodb.

I want to use mongodb's geospatial feature to query locations in a boundary obtained from google maps. It's like withinBox(swLng, swLat, neLng, neLat). But it fails to give me correct results when the map zooms out, as neLng/neLat is less than swLng/swLat. It seems that this is calculated using x > swLng and x < neLng and y > swLat and y < neLat, not taking map projection into account.

So can I achieve the query by withinBox, or I have to adjust coordinates, or I should use near?

Comment: I found this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090690/google-maps-panning-and-zooming-into-areas-markers-not-appearing-when-i-zoom?rq=1) mentions the international date line and also gives a solution in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, when northeast and southwest points cross the international date line, the query will fail as top right's y is smaller than bottom left's y.

If you are using mongodb with php and doctrine, you need make two queries and merge result on the client side like below:

```
if ($x1 > $x2) {
    $qb->field('coordinates')->withinBox(-180, $y1, $x2, $y2);
    $result1 = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    $qb->field('coordinates')->withinBox($x1, $y1, 180, $y2);
    $result2 = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    $result = $result1->toArray() + $result2->toArray();
} else {
    $qb->field('coordinates')->withinBox($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    $result = $result->toArray();
}
```