# Colour-coding points on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm currently developing an application as a page of a college project to display information about house price costs and am looking to implement a colour-coded map for different years. The idea would be that there would be a dot where each house sold was located on a map (Google Maps for example), and colour-coded green to red depending on how expensive it was.

I'm looking for a way to implement this using the Google Maps API, but have been unable to find a solution that doesn't seriously slow up the application as I would be loading in ~30k datapoints for each year and the application currently had 5 years worth of data.

Would anyone have any suggestions on what to use. I've looked at Google's Geocharts and they don't really offer what I am looking for. I've also looked at Heatmaps, and though they get the colouring effect I'm looking for, the points are weighted so the colour is dependent on proximity rather than my specified variable, price.

Comment: Perhaps a FusionTables layer on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30K points * 5 years = 150K markers. That might be too much. You should be looking for a way to show only one year of history at a time and/or use [marker clustering](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/).

Regarding the color markers, you could use SVG markers for that. You can easily change the color of your SVG path. With a little bit of calculation, you should be able to process all your points and define the color in which to draw the markers.

Example round SVG marker:

```
var icon = {
    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: // your marker color,
    fillOpacity: .8,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    strokeWeight: 0
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: // your marker position,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon,
    title: 'some title'
});
```

Here is a quick example:

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rxxtmLfp/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/suggestion. I am planning on rendering the points one year at a time, based on user selection, but what would be the best method to use so as to not slow down the application?
I'm looking for something that's basically just colouring the map where my data-points are and nothing more really.

Comment: What do you mean? What method to use to get the points and plot them on the map? What do you use for your backend? PHP? Where do you want to store the points? File? Database? What type? etc.

Comment: I'm using PHP to pull the lat, lng from a postgres database, and that's not the problem. Its the time it takes to map all the points onto the map that slows things down.

Comment: Did you try it? What would be a resonable amount of time? Apart from that, are you planning to show the whole world map or say, the whole area where your 30k markers are? There are ways to load only the markers that would be visible within the actual map bounds. That will speed things up a lot.

Comment: You can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26884650/1238965) where I tested the time needed to plot 7000 markers on a map. The average load time is 1.8 seconds (with an AJAX request on a flat file). So it should be around 8 seconds for 30k markers. Check [this answer too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21335156/1238965) if you want to know how to restrict your backend to only return points within your map bounds (example is for mysql). And don't forget to upvote if this was helpful! ;-)

Comment: Em I tested this method with 30k points and the load time was ~10 seconds, which makes it look like the application is halting to the end-user. Is there a more efficient way I could go about this?

Comment: Show a spinner while it's loading so the user knows something is going on?